# How do I pass arbitrary arguments in Python

Tags: python, arguments, command-line-arguments, argparse

In the assignment I have to do, I'm supposed to create an alternative to the 'rm' command. I have to pass variable number of arguments like ,

```
$ rm.py /path/to/some/file ./somefile someotherfile
$ rm.py /path/to/some/file ./somefile someotherfile -r
$ rm.py -r /path/to/some/file ./somefile someotherfile
$ rm.py *.java
```

the -r argument can be passed as any argument, at any place. 
the meaning of the -r is the same as in when using the regular 'rm' command.
it recursively removes a directory and its contents within it.

it runs the script, and whichever path is given like

```
rm.py /path/to/some/file
```

it then moves that to the output directory '~/rm_trash'
if there are duplicates, i worry about that as well.

But to start, I'm having some trouble understanding how to approach it. 
Should I go about it in a for loop, and if one of the arguments equals to the '-r' go from there?

Should i import and use argparse?

I have some more questions, but I'd like to first handle what I'm asking above.

Having to post again, still don't understand how I can get the specific argument for any number of argument besides the 'r'

Comment: How does the current code examine arguments right now?  Are you examining the elements of `sys.argv` (for pedagogical reasons) or using an argument-parsing library?

Comment: I posted this earlier and was told to look at the argparse library, and I do think there is some help with it. but I well, don't know if i'm using it correctly, and don't know if i can use it in the assignment.

i was told by a peer that first before everything, to look in a foor loop for the '-r' argument. but how?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Posting some existing code will help provide better answers.  Also, StackOverflow users won't be able to address whether using `argparse` in an assignment is a good idea.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing arbitrary arguments, how should I go about the code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58742214/passing-arbitrary-arguments-how-should-i-go-about-the-code)

Comment: @NicholasM yeah I know, well, at the moment I don't have any code, just psuedo and I don't know if i can post that.

and yes that possible duplicate is my post that got closed and didn't help me when it got closed.

Comment: giving the implementation of **recursive** **remove** command as a homework -- I think it's 11 on a scale from 1 to 10

Comment: @lenik huh? not sure what you're saying

Answer (score 2):

I would use argparse, as you can specify out of order actions:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

Comment: should argparse work even if say I don't use the '-r' command? or if i only call one argument or two, or three, etc?

Comment: as long as it's an optional argument, it will only use it when you specify it.  argparse is very powerful, it should be able to handle all your cases. Here is the howto documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html

Comment: thank you, let me go ahead and read thru it.

what about the other arguments like if its a file, directory, /path/to/file

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `argparse`, or cannot for purposes of an assignment, you could look inside [`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/sys.html):

```
is_recursive = any(arg == '-r' for arg in sys.argv)  

# `paths` will be a list of all other arguments
paths = [arg for arg in sys.argv if arg != '-r']
```

Comment: thank you, let me try this in that case

and what about the other paths, if i want to use the shutil to move the files/directories

i would need a source, i should be able to manipulate the code you posted above for that as well right?

Answer (score 1):

Define a parsing function, which looks for the '-r' string:

```
def parse(alist, astr='-r'):
    try:
        idx = alist.index(astr)
        r = alist.pop(idx)
        return True, alist
    except ValueError:
        return False, alist
```

If we do

```
import sys
r, rest = parse(sys.argv[1:])
```

should give a True/False value for `r`, and a list of file names. Use those in the rest of your code.

Testing:

```
In [326]: list1 = 'rm.py /path/to/some/file ./somefile someotherfile'.split()   
In [329]: r, rest = parse(list1[1:])                                            
In [330]: r, rest                                                               
Out[330]: (False, ['/path/to/some/file', './somefile', 'someotherfile'])

In [331]: list2 = 'rm.py /path/to/some/file ./somefile someotherfile -r'.split()                                                                     
In [332]: r, rest = parse(list2[1:])                                            
In [333]: r, rest                                                               
Out[333]: (True, ['/path/to/some/file', './somefile', 'someotherfile'])
```

To illustrate what happens when '-r' is present:

```
In [335]: list2.index('-r')                                                     
Out[335]: 4
In [336]: list2.pop(4)                                                          
Out[336]: '-r'
In [337]: list2                                                                 
Out[337]: ['rm.py', '/path/to/some/file', './somefile', 'someotherfile']
```

if it isn't present we get a `ValueError`:

```
In [338]: list1.index('-r')                                                     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-338-807fbe60be44> in <module>
----> 1 list1.index('-r')

ValueError: '-r' is not in list
```

======

The equivalent functionality using `argparse`:

```
In [339]: import argparse                                                       
In [340]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()                                    
In [341]: parser.add_argument('-r', action='store_true', help='recursive flag');                                                                       
In [342]: parser.add_argument('rest', nargs='*', help='file names');            
In [343]: args = parser.parse_args(list1[1:])
```

Use `args = parser.parse_args()` to read the `sys.argv`.

The result is a `namespace` object that has the needed attributes:

```
In [344]: args                                                                  
Out[344]: Namespace(r=False, rest=['/path/to/some/file', './somefile', 'someotherfile'])
In [345]: args.r                                                                
Out[345]: False
In [346]: args.rest                                                             
Out[346]: ['/path/to/some/file', './somefile', 'someotherfile']
```

Use `args.r` and `args.rest` in the same way as `r` and `rest` above.

The '-r' can be before or after the list of file names.  `argparse` becomes more useful when you want to define more options like '-r'.  It also takes care of displaying a help message, and meaningful errors.

```
In [347]: parser.parse_args(['--help'])                                         
usage: ipython3 [-h] [-r] [rest [rest ...]]

positional arguments:
  rest        file names

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  -r          recursive flag
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use:

```
os.system( 'rm ' + ' '.join( sys.argv[1:] )
```

and get it done.